# How do you view the full AWS SES error message?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, woocommerce, amazon-ses

**CURRENTLY**

1. I use AWS SES with my Wordpress site and WooCommerce plugin.
2. Emails sent to @bigpond.net users fail

**ISSUE**

I want to examine the unique 16 character message ID, and a code looking like IBxxx where xxx is a series of numbers, but this is not provided to me by Wordpress / WooCommerce.

All I get sent is:

Subject: Delivery Status Notification (Failure)

```
from:   MAILER-DAEMON@ap-southeast-2.amazonses.com
to:     my@emailaddress.com
date:   Jan 15, 2022, 1:00 PM
subject:    Delivery Status Notification (Failure)
mailed-by:  4444-444.smtp-out.ap-region-1.amazonses.com
signed-by:  amazonses.com
```

> An error occurred while trying to deliver the mail to the following recipients:
> user@bigpond.com

**QUESTION**

How can I access the full error message sent from Bigpond?

Comment: I think you need to contact Bigpond support. Are you sure the email is correct? Have you tried sending a test email from another email service to confirm the issue is with aws service or all?

Comment: Email is correct. It's multiple emails always @bigpond.net, and yes, I've contacted Bigpond support and they requested this information.

Comment: I think I had misunderstood the question the first time(or maybe not on a second thought)..anyways, aws can give you more detail about your mail logs. You need to contact aws support(if you can). I have a sample of a failed delivery message log by aws(I had asked from support) and to be honest there isn't much. Maybe they sent me just a part and not the whole message log. These logs are not available to the customer and are provided on demand.

Comment: @riz, I contacted AWS support and they provided me with the error message! It was exactly what I needed thank you. Would you like to post your answer and I will select as the answer :)

Comment: Hi @Wronski, I am glad that your issue has been resolved. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of some services(`vpn` and `ses` are the ones I know of), AWS doesn't share the logs directly with the customer. You need to open a support ticket and ask for the logs. In my case i have noticed that they don't always share the full log with you but only the part which interests you.